# stop a previuos run of a task in tasker

Tags: tasker

let's say i can a task called `my_task`. If i add a stop action and the beginning of the task:

```
stop my_task
```

`my_task` will stop inmediatly. What i want is, when `my_task` executes, it should check if it was already executing before, then stop that other instance of itself, and then continue with the rest of the task... Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what Tasker offers by default: if a task is already running, either the new instance stops immediately (default IIRC) or the already running one gets stopped. Should be in the advanced setting of the task:

[image: Task Properties]

Tap the settings button (bottom right in the screenshot) to open this screen, then chose in the drop-down box for "Collision Handling":

- **Abort New Task:** The task won't be executed while another instance is already running
- **Abort Existing Task:** If there's already an instance running, abort that and run the new one
- **Run Both Together:** Let them collide, no matter how often